# running powershell command from c# webservice

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running a powershell command from c#, which I call through a webservice

This is the command `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity`

Here is my code.

```
string command = "Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity " + user;
```

The user I pass through the webservice.

However when I run it I get this error.

`System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The term &#39;Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity babbey&#39; is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I'm not sure where the &#39 is coming from before and after my command.  However, if I take out the +user part it works fine.  So my problem is the variable that is in the command variable.

Comment: The &#39 is a red herring: it's the error message getting escaped, it's not your input. Could you please post the rest of your code (where you do something interesting with **command**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `PowerShell.AddCommand`, you only specify the command name e.g. `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration`.  Then you call AddParameter on the command to add the parameter e.g.:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration");
ps.AddParameter("Identity", user);
```